# SSRS How to repeat displaying a table in each page of SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a table contains 4 rows and I want to put it in the header of the page so I can dispayed in each page of the SSRS report.I will export my report with the pdf option.

Is that possible to do that ? Can you please help me and thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can put things in headers, but there are limitations. You can't, for example, reference items in your datasets. At the moment, you are simply asking "can I put tablix in the header" to which the answer is "yes", however, I doubt that is what you are really asking here. What is your final goal here? What have you tried and where have you got stuck? Also you've tagged 3 different versions of SSRS. I've removed those tags, please only tag the relevant version of SSRS.

Comment: @Larnu  curious question can we add dynamic data to header of page? I mean do we not need these 4 rows static for all the pages. Trying to get info.

Comment: Can you define/elaborate on "dynamic data"?

Comment: Hi guys, I think I get a solution for my problem, I create parameters to each column of my dataset (Default values and I allow blank value and multiple values) and I call each value by Parametes! Name_Parameter.Value(Number_of_value_in_the_list)

Comment: I mean a tablix data coming from dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get a solution for my problem, I create parameters to each column of my dataset (Default values and I allow blank value and multiple values) and I call each value by Parametes! Name_Parameter.Value(Number_of_value_in_the_list) in the textbox.
Here screenshots explain what I did

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMqvJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Z77.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Xr0.png)